# KStreams Grouping by multiple fields to get count

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

So I have a bunch of records in a topic like the one below. I can create the GroupBy in KSQLDB with no problem as it is more SQL than anything else. But I have been tasked to move it over to Java KStreams and am failing miserably.

Can someone guide me on the Topology for first grouping by user_id then Object_id then by day? I don't ask this lightly as I have tried over and over with state stores with so many examples but I am just chasing my tail. Basically, I would like to know how many times a user looked at a specific object on a given day.

Anything on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
    "entrytimestamp": "2020-05-04T15:21:01.897",
    "user_id": "080db36a-f205-4e32-a324-cc375b75d167",
    "object_id": "fdb084f7-5367-4776-a5ae-a10d6e898d22"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create composed key, and then group by key, like:

```
KStream<String, Message> stream = builder.stream(MESSAGES, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
KStream<String, Message> newKeyStream = stream.selectKey((key, message) ->
            String.format("%s-%s-%s",
                    message.userId(),
                    message.objectId(),
                    LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(message.timestamp()), ZoneId.systemDefault())));
KGroupedStream<String, Message> groupedBy = newKeyStream.groupByKey();
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time. I used your code and viola it worked.